# Parameter username of loadUserByUsername in custom UserDetailsService is always empty

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am working on a form based login using spring-security with a customized UserDetailsService. The login form seems to be submitted correctly. While debugging the application I found out that the submitted request arrived at the attemptAuthentication method of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. But it looks like the the request parameter cannot be mapped to the username and password field because they remain empty. Therefore also the parameter username of the loadByUsername method of my custom UserDetailsService remains empty and I am not able to successfully login.

I have tried a lot, but for now I have no clue what the problem could be. I am also quite new to spring-security, but I suppose I am not too far away.

I summarized the code as much as possible. If you need more information please let me now.

First I set up the springSecurityFilterChain in web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filter Config -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Filter Mappings -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

That is my applicationContext.xml with the reference to customUserDetailsService:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>

<!-- Authentification -->
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.seraphim.security.auth.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.seraphim"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

The applicationContext-security.xml with the appropriate authentication-provider:

```
<http
    auto-config="true"
    access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">

    <intercept-url
            pattern="/pages/**"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url
            pattern="/**"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

    <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/index.xhtml"
            default-target-url="/pages/main.xhtml"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.xhtml"/>

    <logout
            logout-url="/logout*"
            logout-success-url="/"/>

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

In faces-config.xml I have added a LoginErrorPhaseListener to detect BadCredentialsException and added the LoginBean:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.seraphim.security.auth.LoginErrorPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.seraphim.bean.LoginBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>
        request
    </managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

index.xhtml is has username an password field an is submitted to the loginBean:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">

    <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="User:"/>
    <p:inputText id='j_username' label="user" required="true"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:"/>

    <h:inputSecret id='j_password' label="pass2" required="true"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="_spring_security_remember_me" value="Remember "/>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id='_spring_security_remember_me'/>

    <h:outputLabel/>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" value="Login"/>

</h:form>
```

LoginBean.java

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class LoginBean {

  public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {

    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
    return null;

  }
}
```

Now in CustomUserDetailsService.java the correct user should be loaded, but here the method parameter username is always empty (not null). And therefore of course no valid user is found:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Resource
IUserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
    }

    // build roles for user
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    if(user.isAdmin()) {
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(),
            user.isEnabled(), 
            user.isAccountNonExpired(),
            user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), 
            user.isAccountNonLocked(),
            authorities);
}

}
```

Hope you can help me on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate Spring Security with JSF this way you need to set `prependId = "false"` in your form, otherwise field names required by Spring Security will be prepended with form id:

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId = "false">...</h:form>
```