# loginId not passed to UserDetailsService for spring security

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

In spring security, using `class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService`   and method  `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)`    with `<input id="j_username" type="text" placeholder="Log-in ID"/>`   the **email** (as login id) is not passed to the `loadUserByUsername()`. I meant its blank `""` even if I give it some text. what can be the reasons of it?

---

Chrome <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

---

[Parameter username of loadUserByUsername in custom UserDetailsService is always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390655/parameter-username-of-loaduserbyusername-in-custom-userdetailsservice-is-always) is similar, but not relevant I guess?

---

Some main important error logs.

```
the email passed from CustomUserDetailsService in method loadUserByUsername is: 
debug ---- 1
email entered for lookup was : 
debug --- a
debug --- b
Hibernate: select users0_.id as id1_15_, users0_.description as descript2_15_, users0_.email as email3_15_, users0_.isEnabled as isEnable4_15_, users0_.name as name5_15_, users0_.password as password6_15_, users0_.type as type7_15_ from Users users0_ where users0_.email=?
print Error in retrieving user
Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at web.dao.impl.jpa.UsersDAOImpl.getUserByLoginId(UsersDAOImpl.java:67)
    at web.service.common.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

login.jsp form

```
                                  <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">

                  <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <img style="height:30px;" src="company.png" />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                      </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>
                          <img style="height:30px;" src="person.png" />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <input id="j_username" type="text" placeholder="Log-in ID"/>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log-In" />
                      </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <img style="height:30px;" src="password.png" />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <input id="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <input type="reset" />
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align:right;">
                        Forgot your password?
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      </td>
                    </tr>


                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </form>
```

CustomUserDetailService

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package web.service.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import web.dao.UsersDAO;
import web.dao.impl.jpa.UsersDAOImpl;
import web.entity.Users;


/**
 *
 * @author syncsys
 */
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{


   @Resource
   private UsersDAO userDAO;


 /**
  * Retrieves a springUser record containing the springUser's credentials and access.
  */
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
   throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {


  // Declare a null Spring User
  UserDetails springUser = null;

  try {
    System.out.println("the email passed from CustomUserDetailsService in method loadUserByUsername is: " +email);
   // Search database for a springUser that matches the specified email
   // You can provide a custom DAO to access your persistence layer
   // Or use JDBC to access your database
   // DbUser is our custom domain springUser. This is not the same as Spring's User
      System.out.println("debug ---- 1");
   Users dbUser = userDAO.getUserByLoginId(email);

   // Populate the Spring User object with details from the dbUser
   // Here we just pass the email, password, and access level
   // getAuthorities() will translate the access level to the correct role type
 System.out.println("debug ---- 2");
   springUser =  new User(
     dbUser.getEmail(),
     dbUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
     true,
     true,
     true,
     true,
     //getAuthorities(dbUser.getAccess()) );
     getAuthorities(2) );
 System.out.println("debug ---- 3");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("print Error in retrieving user");
   e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");
  }
   System.out.println("debug ---- 4");
  // Return springUser to Spring for processing.
  // Take note we're not the one evaluating whether this springUser is authenticated or valid
  // We just merely retrieve a springUser that matches the specified email
  return springUser;
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves the correct ROLE type depending on the access level, where access level is an Integer.
  * Basically, this interprets the access value whether it's for a regular springUser or admin.
  *
  * @param access an integer value representing the access of the springUser
  * @return collection of granted authorities
  */
  public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
   // Create a list of grants for this springUser
   List<GrantedAuthority> authList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);

   // All users are granted with ROLE_USER access
   // Therefore this springUser gets a ROLE_USER by default
   System.out.println("Grant ROLE_USER to this user");
   authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));

   // Check if this springUser has admin access
   // We interpret Integer(1) as an admin springUser

//   if ( access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
//    // User has admin access
//    logger.debug("Grant ROLE_ADMIN to this user");
//    authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
//   }

   // Return list of granted authorities
   return authList;
   }

}
```

User Dao

```
package web.dao.impl.jpa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import web.dao.UsersDAO;
import web.entity.Users;



/**
 * 
 * @version $Revision$
 * @since   1.0
 */
@Repository
public class UsersDAOImpl implements UsersDAO {

    /**
     * The JPA entity manager
     */
//        @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Set the entity manager
     * 
     * @param entityManager
     */

        /**
     * Saves or Updates an existing user entity instance.
     * 
     * @param user  the user entity
     * @return      the managed user entity instance
     */
    public Users saveOrUpdate(Users user) {
        if(user.getId() == 0) {
            entityManager.persist(user);
                        return user;

        }
        else
            entityManager.merge(user);
                        return user;
    }

        public Users getUserByLoginId(String email){
            System.out.println("email entered for lookup was : "+email);
            System.out.println("debug --- a");
            String queryString = "SELECT user FROM Users AS user " +
                         "WHERE user.email = :email";
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
            System.out.println("debug --- b");
            query.setParameter("email", email);

            List<?> list = query.getResultList();

            System.out.println("email retrieved is" +((Users)list.get(0)).getEmail() );
            System.out.println("debug --- c");
            if(list == null || list.size() == 0) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
           Users user = (Users)list.get(0);
           System.out.println("debug --- d");
           System.out.println(user.getEmail());
           return user;
//            return (Users)list.get(0);

        }


    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to return the hibernate session from the JPA
     * entity manager implementation.
     * 
     * @return the hibernate {#link Session}
     */
    protected Session getHibernateSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }



}
```

User Controller

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package web.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import web.entity.Users;
import web.service.UserService;

/**
 *
 * @author syncsys
 */
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error,
      ModelMap model) {
     System.out.println("Received request to show login page");

     // Add an error message to the model if login is unsuccessful
     // The 'error' parameter is set to true based on the when the authentication has failed.
     // We declared this under the authentication-failure-url attribute inside the spring-security.xml
     /* See below:
      <form-login
       login-page="/krams/auth/login"
       authentication-failure-url="/krams/auth/login?error=true"
       default-target-url="/krams/main/common"/>*/
     if (error == true) {
      // Assign an error message
      model.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
     } else {
      model.put("error", "");
     }

     // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp
     return "login";
    }

//    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create" )
    public String creatUser(ModelMap model){
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setEmail("myemail@mydomain.com");
        user.setName("myname");
        userService.saveOrUpdate(user);
        System.out.println("created--------------------");
        return "create";       
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String showUsers(ModelMap model){
        return "index";       
    }


    @RequestMapping("/loginfail")
    public String loginFail(ModelMap model){
        return "login-fail";       
    }
}
```

Dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
>


    <context:component-scan base-package="web" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"       />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"    />
    </context:component-scan> 
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
<!--  <context:annotation-config />-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<!--          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">-->

<!--             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >-->
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>        

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
          <property name="viewName" value="index" />
    </bean>



     <!---
     ##########################################################################
    Hibernate

    -->
<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="abc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="web.entity" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    ###########################################################
    -->


<!--

    JPA based instead of hibernate

-->
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<!-- 
        This configures the EntityManagerFactory object used for JPA/Spring managed persistent objects. 
     -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence-unit-demo" /> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="packagesToScan" value="web.entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
<!--    giving errors       <property name="databasePlatorm" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>-->
<!--                                <property name="database" value="HSQL" />-->
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />                        
            </bean>
        </property>   
                <property name="jpaProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>                         
    </bean> 
    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    <!-- Pulls database connection from the tomcat container's context database pool via JNDI -->
<!--    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mssqlserver" resource-ref="true"/>-->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
            <property name="username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="password" value="abc" />
        </bean>



    <!--
        Sets up our transaction manager. 
     -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!-- giving errors               <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
                </property>-->
    </bean>

        <!--
        Defines our transaction manager for Transactional annotations.
     -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory" />





</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>



       <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

    <import resource="springDispatcher-servlet.xml" />

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/loginfail" >

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll"/>
<!--  <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>-->
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/tem/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>


  <security:form-login
    login-page="/login"
    authentication-failure-url="/loginfail?error=true"
    default-target-url="/index"/>

  <security:logout
    invalidate-session="true"
    logout-success-url="/logout"
    logout-url="/logout"/>

 </security:http>

 <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
 <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
  <!--         <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>-->
         </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>

 <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database 
 <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
 -->
 <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
 <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="web.service.common.CustomUserDetailsService"/>





</beans>
```

Comment: That's too big a wall of text for me to look through all, or even most of it. I do have a question though. Have you tried logging in using a tool to hit the service directly (without using the page), like Jmeter? Or have you tried debugging the moment you enter the spring security filter chain to see if what you receive from the page contains a user name? If you enter the form with Chrome you should be able to inspect the passed request parameters / body and see.

Comment: @CorayThan Thanks for reply. I have made some debug system.outs, confirmed the spring core annotations and beans work. but iam new to spring and spring security. I do not know how to check what you are saying. how to check why its not passing the param `id="j_username"`     to the `UserDetailsService` ?

Comment: I'd start by using chrome or firefox to inspect the request that's being sent to the server. In Chrome `ctrl+shift+i` then go to the "network" tab, then try posting the form.

Comment: When you do that you should be able to see something like this in the request body: `j_username=mrpostal&j_password=password&submit=Login`

Comment: @CorayThan Theres not `request body` nor `j_username=mrpostal&j_password=password&submit=Login`. I have posted a snapshot in the EDIT. and 2. the form uses `POST` and not `GET`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like your issue is probably with your form page set up. There should be a `Query String Parameters` or `Request Payload` in there, I think.

Comment: @CorayThan its solved. I just answered. thanks a lot for your guidance. May God bless  you and all other open source open haarted community helpers

Comment: You might consider removing irrelevant parts from your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:) just added `name=j_username` in  `<input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" placeholder="Log-in ID"/>` and it worked.

Thanks to l3eta on Rizon irc chat network.